# Listing droplets with a specific tag name with Digital Ocean NPM

Tags: node.js, digital-ocean

I have an express web application where one of the required capabilities is to show a user all their Digital Ocean droplets. I'm using the Digital Ocean NPM module - https://www.npmjs.com/package/digitalocean - so my application can create, delete, list etc. from Digital Ocean. In order to show the user only their own droplets, when they create a droplet a tag is added with the users ID. What I want to do now is list only the droplets with their ID as a tag.

I know from viewing the Digital Ocean API docs - https://developers.digitalocean.com/documentation/v2/#listing-droplets-by-tag - That it's possible to list droplets by a given tag. Also, the NPM module allows you to list droplets while passing query parameters, like so: client.droplets.list([queryObject,] [callback])

However, I'm not sure how to convert the language of CURL from the API to the Node module as I'm useless with CURL.

What I have tried so far:

```
client.droplets.list(["tags", req.user.id]).then((droplets) => {
     // Do something
});

and 

client.droplets.list(["tag_name", req.user.id]).then((droplets) => {
     // Do something
});
```

The first attempt uses the word "tags" as this is the language used by the NPM module. The second attempt uses "tag_name" as this is what the API uses to list by tags.

However, neither of these work. They don't fail and throw errors, but they just continue to list all the droplets available on my Digital Ocean account and not those with the user ID as a tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `droplet.list()` method accepts a query object ([docs](http://phillbaker.github.io/digitalocean-node/Droplet.html#list), [code](https://github.com/phillbaker/digitalocean-node/blob/master/lib/digitalocean/droplet.js#L14-L21)) as the first parameter. So to list only Droplets with a certain tag, you can use:

```js
client.droplets.list({'tag_name': 'mytag'}).then((droplets) => {
    droplets.forEach(function(d, i) {
      console.log(d.id, d.name);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew! Really appreciate it